# Add custom attribute to an HTML input element with C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web-applications

I'm using the following method to add a custom attribute to a check box:

```
CheckBox chkBx = new CheckBox();
chkBx.ID = "chk" + n;
chkBx.Attributes["itemname"] = strtemPath;
```

But as a result I'm getting the following HTML:

```
<span itemname="Some folder"><input id="MainContent_chk0" type="checkbox" name="MasterPg$MainContent$chk0" /></span>
```

where I'm expecting this:

```
<input id="MainContent_chk0" type="checkbox" name="MasterPg$MainContent$chk0" itemname="Some folder" />
```

Any idea how to correct the C# code to get my expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
chkBx.InputAttributes.Add("itemname", strtemPath);
```

Comment: You got it, my friend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
chkBx.Attributes.Add("itemname", strtemPath);
```

- [**AttributeCollection.Add Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.add.aspx)

Comment: As I said above it produces the same result...